# How to set the value of a field when inserting the results of a MySQL query into a table

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that will insert its results into a table:

```
INSERT INTO search_results (rec_type, id, name)
SELECT user_id AS id, name
FROM organizations 
WHERE name LIKE '%Smith%'
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY name
```

How would I set the value of rec_type for all the records found, 'rec_type = "personel"', in this query or would I have to do a second query and use UPDATE to set the value of rec_type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the string in the `SELECT` list.

```
INSERT INTO search_results (rec_type, id, name)
SELECT 'personel' AS rec_type, user_id AS id, name
FROM organizations 
WHERE name LIKE '%Smith%'
ORDER BY name
```

There's no point in using `GROUP BY` when you're not using any aggregation functions (e.g. `MAX()`, `COUNT()`, `SUM()`). If there are duplicate results, use `SELECT DISTINCT` to suppress them.